# Twitter Bootstrap - why row class has margin-left: -20px?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't understand why row class has `margin-left: -20px` (so it grows after parents border like on the image). I think nobody needs this behavior. Or am I doing something wrong?

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="top-container" class="row">
            <div class="span8">
                <h1>App</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: example]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969051/bootstrap-3-why-is-row-class-is-wider-than-its-container

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use row-fluid instead of row, then your span4 and span8 won't have margin-left.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="top-container" class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8">
            <h1>App</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My library is bootstrap v3.2.0, doesn't have a class named row-fluid. Am I missing something?

Comment: @hasany See answer above mine for Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 3):

For people trying to find this out for Bootstrap 3:

> Grids and full-width layouts Folks looking to create fully fluid
>   layouts (meaning your site stretches the entire width of the viewport)
>   must wrap their grid content in a containing element with padding: 0
>   15px; to offset the margin: 0 -15px; used on .rows.

[Source](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) (search for `Grids and full-width layouts`)